# Instance of future void - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I try to make it show the translation but it doesn't work :(

I am new to this and appreciate your help, I know almost nothing about flutter.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final translator = GoogleTranslator();
final input = summary;

// Using the Future API
var translation = translator
    .translate(input, to: 'es')
    .then((result) => print("Source: $input\nTranslated: $result"));

return Column(
  children: [
    const SectionTitle(title: "Información"),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20),
      child: Text(("$translation"),
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.55),
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put those types of operations in the `build` method as that could be run 60 times per second (actually even more).

Read a bit about [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) (and `StatefulWidget`) to get a feeling for where you could put the `translator` and where you could call the `translate()` method.

The example in the link call a future that is put into the variable `_calculation`, consider that being the result of your `translate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Include other imports


class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final translator = GoogleTranslator();
  String translation = ""; // assuming result is a string
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getTranslation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SectionTitle(title: "Información"),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20),
          child: _isLoading
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : Text((translation),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.55),
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
        ),
        //Bonus
        TextButton(
            child: Text("Get translation"),
            onPressed: () async {
              await _getTranslation();
            }),
      ],
    );
  }

  _getTranslation() async {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      translator.translate("to translation", to: 'es').then((result) {
        setTranslation(result);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
    } on TimeoutException catch (_) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (_) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  setTranslation(String value) {
    setState(() {
      translation = value;
    });
  }

  setIsLoading(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = value;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'.
    setState(()=> _isLoading = value);
    ^^^^^^^^ 

Error: Final field 'summary' is not initialized.
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor.
  final String summary;
               ^^^^^^^

Comment: @Ow3 I have changed my answer

Comment: Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'.
  setState(()=> _isLoading = value);
  ^^^^^^^^
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'.
  setState(()=> translation = value);
  ^^^^^^^^
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setIsLoading'.
  setIsLoading(false);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
The worst thing is that I don't understand anything, thanks for helping me

Comment: @Ow3 I have changed my answer for the last time. If it doesn't work i don't know anything else. Meanwhile this is the course that laid my foundation in Flutter: https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps/learn/lecture/19510590?start=0#overview. Try to see if you can get it on discount